# Couldn't mount file The disk image file is corrupted

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, virtualbox, mount, dd

Not so long ago I Backed up Entire Windows 10 partition of my drive using dd under ubuntu and since then I have two main problems - first it turned out that even the unused space is imaged which is quite bad considering that the drive was 80/150GB full.

And even worse I couldn't mount it in Windows using it's built in mount function(even though it was completely fine to open the image with 7zip). I didn't bother with these problembs back then but now I want to run the OS in VirtualBox and cannot mount the image in the VM also.

Does anyone has any ideas how to resolve these problems? Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: `dd` copies disc sectors blindly, so it cannot take account of the occupancy of whatever file system is being copied. However, if the unused space is zeroed, then the output image file will compress well. I use VMware, so I cannot help with VBox problems.

Comment: see if this helps: https://www.forensicfocus.com/Forums/viewtopic/t=15861/  dd makes an exact duplicate of your disk, Windows wants a VHD format to mount, not what dd creates. There are tools for creating virtual disk containers, like disk2vhd.

Answer (score 1):

#### `Not so long ago I Backed up Entire Windows 10 partition of my drive using dd`

Did you image the entire disk? `dd if=/dev/sda of=/path/to/disk.img status=progress`
Or, did you image just the Windows partition? `dd if=/dev/sda2 of=/path/to/disk.img status=progress`

If you did the latter, that explains why Windows cannot mount it; as far as I know, mounting disk images under Windows requires that the image in question have a valid partition table, **which imaging a single partition will not do**.

#### `it turned out that even the unused space is imaged which is quite bad considering that the drive was 80/150GB full`

You can use your favorite partitioning tool (like gparted) to reduce the size of the partition to its used extent. GParted can modify disk images by launching from it from the terminal, with the path to your disk image as an argument:
`gparted /path/to/disk.img`, and then use truncate to reduce the size of the entire image with something like **(careful with this, it can easily render data unreadable)**: 
`truncate -s 81GB /path/to/disk.img`

#### `I want to run the OS in VirtualBox and cannot mount the image in the VM also.`

This can only be done if you can find the Windows EFI bootloader, which is stored on the ESP (EFI System Partition), which is (obviously) a separate partition on your drive, **which only exists in the disk image if you imaged the entire drive. The path to it is (EFI System Partition)/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi**

If you have the bootloader I'll edit my post with instructions to boot it using VirtualBox.